# Creating a const char* const* array

Tags: c++, pointers, boost-python, arrays

I wish to call a 3rd party library function, which accepts a `const char* const*` as argument type:-

```
class Arguments
{
public:
    Arguments(int argc, const char* const* p_argv = 0);
private:
    deque<std::string> m_Args;
}
```

In the library implementations, the passed object is usually a (const) pointer to the first element of `char** argv`. The strings are then cached in a private member variable (`m_Args`), so I *think* the pointers in `p_argv` only need to be valid for the duration of the construction.

**Main question:** How can I, or should I create that `const char* const* p_argv` variable?

---

**More explanation**

I'm trying to pass objects converted from other array types (Boost Python `list`s and `tuple`s) and am trying to find a safe ([RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) way to do so.

I'll be doing this in a number of different places in my code, so I've tried to implement reusable functions that can do the type conversion(s) for me. e.g.

```
// File : converter.hpp

///! ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer
///
///  Convert a Python list to const char* const*.
/// \param   list   - Python list of strings to convert. [in]
/// \param   pargv - array of const char pointers.      [in/out]
/// \returns - const pointer to first element in const char* array.

const char* const* ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer(
    const boost::python::list& list, const char** pargv);
```

I hoped that `pargv` could be created on the stack, from a function that then calls both `ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer` and `store_arguments`. However, unit-tests on the code show that the stored strings become invalid when restored from the `Arguments` class. (This makes sense; I allocate the storage for the array of pointers, but not for the strings that those pointers point to).

---

**Converter implementations**

The original `ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer` implementation was:-

*On the stack*

```
// File : converter.cpp

const char* const* ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer(
    const boost::python::list& list, const char** pargv)
{
    boost::python::stl_input_iterator<std::string> cur_key(list), end;
    std::string temp_s;
    int i=0;
    while (cur_key != end)
    {
        // Get current arg as std::string
        temp_s = (*cur_key++);
        // Save string as a const char*, in pargv[i]
        pargv[i++] = temp_s.c_str();
    }
    pargv[i] = NULL;
    // Validation code...
    const char* const* m_argv = &pargv[0];
    return m_argv;
}
```

To see exactly what was going on, I deployed a load of print statements. Where it says `Validation code...`, I currently have:-

```
    printf("returning address (pargv[0]) of %s (%p)\n", pargv[0], &pargv[0]);
    printf("pargv[1] of %s (%p)\n", pargv[1], &pargv[1]);
    printf("pargv[2] of %s (%p)\n", pargv[2], &pargv[2]);
    printf("pargv[3] of %s (%p)\n", pargv[3], &pargv[3]);
    if (&pargv[0] == &pargv[1])
        printf("addresses of pargv[0] and [1] are the same\n");
```

With the above `ConvertPyList...` implementation, given the Python list `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`, these print statements show:-

```
returning address (pargv[0]) of baz (0x7fffffffa410)
pargv[1] of bar (0x7fffffffa418)
pargv[2] of baz (0x7fffffffa420)
pargv[3] of (null) (0x7fffffffa428)
```

It should obviously show `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, where it instead shows `baz`, `bar`, `baz`.

---

**Getting it to work** - *`malloc` and copy the string*

The only way I have been able to get `foo`, `bar` and `baz` to agree, is to call `malloc` for each `char*` stored in `pargv`:-

```
const char* const* pyblast::ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer(
    int argc, const boost::python::list& list, const char** pargv)
{
    int i=0;
    boost::python::stl_input_iterator<std::string> cur_key(list), end;
    char* cur_ptr;
    while (cur_key != end)
    {
        // Allocate memory on heap.
        cur_ptr = (char*) malloc( strlen( (*cur_key).c_str() ) );
        // Copy string into malloc'd memory
        if (cur_ptr)
            strcpy(cur_ptr, (*cur_key).c_str());
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failure!\n");
        // Save pointer.
        pargv[i++] = cur_ptr;
        ++cur_key;
    }
    pargv[i] = NULL;
    // Validation code...
    const char* const* m_argv = &pargv[0];
    return m_argv;
}
```

But now I have a load of duplicate string's which I need to free myself in the calling code. Is there a safer, RAII kind of way to create this `const char* const*` array?

Perhaps there is a standard type of pointer (in STL or Boost) that could be used here. Using `boost::make_shared` didn't seem to do the trick...

---

**Unit testing code**

If you wish to compile, or test the code yourself, the following should help:-

I've created the following C++ test file:-

```
/// File: test_converters.cpp

#include "converter.hpp"

// Easiest just to include the source whilst testing...
#include "converter.cpp"

#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>

// Create and return the Python list: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
boost::python::list make_dummy_list(void)
{
    boost::python::list dummy_list = boost::python::list();
    dummy_list.append("foo");
    dummy_list.append("bar");
    dummy_list.append("baz");
    return dummy_list;
}

int TestPyListConverter(void)
{
    // Create data to be tested.
    boost::python::list py_argv = make_dummy_list();
    ssize_t argc = boost::python::len(py_argv);
    const char* pargv[argc+1];    //< pointer array
    const char* const* m_pargv =  //< type we're converting to / testing.
        pyblast::ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer(argc, py_argv, pargv);
    // Free pargv, if necessary...

    /// Tests, from Python perspective:-
    ssize_t i = 0;  // current index on m_pargv
    char* p_argv;   // temporary pointer
    while (m_pargv[i] != NULL && i <= argc)
    {
        p_argv = PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem(argv.ptr(), i) );
        if( strcmp(m_pargv[i++], p_argv)  != 0)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception,
                "Test failed. m_pargv[i] != p_argv.");
            boost::python::throw_error_already_set();
        }
        if (i > 4) // didn't find NULL pointer at end of array.
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_converter)
{
    boost::python::def("test_py_list_converter",  &TestPyListConverter);
}
```

N.B. Although this works when using `malloc`, it looks to me like memory-leaking code, as the pointers in pargv are not `free`'d. Ideally, the calling code wouldn't need to worry about that...

This can be compiled with the command:

```
$ gcc -O1 -shared -g -pipe -fstack-protector -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I./ ./test_converters.cpp -o ./test_converter.so -lboost_python -lpython2.7
```

and executed with:

```
$ python -c 'import test_converter; test_converter.test_py_list_converter()'
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to create an array that decays to `const char* const*`; you should need to worry only about creating an array that decays to `char**` (that is, an array of `char*`) or to `const char**` (an array of `const char*`).  The `const` qualifiers are just a promise that `Arguments` won't modify your array (or its strings).

Comment: Yes, returning `const char**` works as well as returning `const char* const*`. Still worrying about how to best create that `char**`, though..

Answer (score 1):

If your main question is, how to convert a queue to const char* const * , then: A pointer to something is used sometimes to to point to the first element of an array of somethings. So in case of const char* const * , a pointer to the first element of an array with pointers to array to char is probably meant. For every array, there must be some kind of protocol to denote the length of the arrays. In case of const char*, this might be a C string, that is usually terminated with 0. For the array of pointers to pointers to char, 0 can also be used to indicate the end of the array. Back to your question:

You can use a std::vector and initialize it with the values returned by std::string.c_str() for all elements of the queue. Add a last 0-pointer to the vector. Now you can convert the address of the first element of the vector to const char* const *.

Not, that the pointer you get is only valid as long as the vector of pointers and the queue of strings is valid.

```
std::deque< std::string > input;
std::vector< const char* > v;

for ( std::deque< std::string >::const_iterator i = input.begin(); i != input.end(); ++i )
    v.push_back( i->c_str() );

v.push_back( 0 );

const char* const * p = &v[ 0 ];
```

Comment: Yes, I did try using `std::vector`, but not like this... I'm not working with a `deque` - above, the `deque` is private to the 3rd party library - but the `const_iterator` technique should apply just as well to `boost::python::list`s and `tuple`s, which I am using. Thanks!

Comment: In C++11, use `const char* const* p = v.data()` instead of `= &v[0]`.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to work if I put it into `ConvertPyListToCharArrayPointer`. Even if returning the vector, `v` (not `&v[0]`), it ends up containing `["baz", "baz", "baz"]`, not `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`...

Comment: @AlexLeach From what you write, it sound like, you inserted the very same pointer three times, or you added some kind of alias to one string. You have to make sure, that the vector, containing the pointers is valid as long as you use the pointer to the first element of the vector. But maybe it's the python iterator, that causing problems, by making copies of the element. Try to copy all strings into a std::vector first or see, if address of the string, the iterator is pointing to is every time the same (&*cur_key).